# iPhone simulator and applicationWillTerminate()

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

When my app is run in the iPhone simulator, the delegate method

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

is only called the first time I hit the iPhone simulator's home button.

After the home button is pressed and the app is launched again, hitting the home button does not call the delegate method.

What is going on here?  Am I misunderstanding something fundamental?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suspect that it is being called, but that you are getting confused because after you hit the Home button in the Simulator, you've ended the current session in Xcode. You probably have an `NSLog` in your `applicationWillTerminate:` method, yes? Once you hit the Home button, `NSLog`s no longer show up in Xcode's run console. If you open `/Applications/Console.app` I expect they'll show up there.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Calls to NSLog() do not appear after the first time returned to the Home screen.  However all other function calls called from the delegate continue to operate as per usual.  Thanks!

Comment: Xcode no longer pays attention to the logging output from the iPhone Simulator after you terminate the program and return to Springboard. Everything still functions exactly the same except output won't go to Xcode's run log.

Comment: I can we differentiate the (application termination due to some phone call and resuming it from previous state) and (application launch) ?

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

is called when the application "terminates".
If you are using iOS then the app will NOT terminate when the home button is pressed, unless you have disabled multi-tasking for your app or the user does not have a "multi-tasking supported" device.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground {
```

is now used when the user presses the home button. Unless (as I previously said) you have disabled multi-tasking for your app or the user does not have a "multi-tasking supported" device.