# XCode/Instruments not showing memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, instruments

I'm following the Stanford iOS development lectures and I have a Calculator brain class which has been `alloc init` in a controller but I haven't `release`d it in the `dealloc`.

```
- (CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
    if (!brain) 
        brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];

    return brain;

}
```

I ran from XCode -> Run with Performance Tool and the app started and no leaks appeared, I then clicked the home button in the iOS Simulator and nothing, I then double clicked the home button and closed the app and still nothing.

I also did Build & Analyse and it didnt spot anything

Could you let me know why its not picking it up?

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense. Can you please edit it?

Comment: Are you using XCode 4.2 with Automatic Reference Counting?

Comment: No I'm using XCode 3.2.6

Comment: Was there a autorelease pool in main.

Comment: There is. Could you explain how that works. Is it a massive wrapper to tidy things up and you therefore don't have to worry about dealloc etc (not that I wouldn't do memory management properly)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears as if there is no *detectable* leak.  Look at this line:

```
brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
```

As long as `brain` points to an object, that object won't be considered a "memory leak".  If at some point you do this,

```
brain = nil;
```

Then the leak will register.  Deallocating the container object will also achieve this, but are you *sure* it's being deallocated?  (It won't be deallocated when your program exits, for example.)

**The problem:** Leak detectors *cannot* detect all memory leaks -- this is a mathematically proven fact.  Most detectors only detect unreachable objects, and many leak detectors are especially susceptible to false negatives -- in C it is hard to tell the difference at runtime between a pointer and an integer.

**Edit:** It sounds like your application only ever creates one instance of the controller, which only creates one instance of `CalculatorBrain`.  If you think about what a memory leak really *is*, you can define it as unused memory that your program does not release back to the operating system.

- While the program is running, `CalculatorBrain` is always in use and therefore it is not a leak.
- When the program exits, the operating system automatically reclaims all memory used by your process, therefore there cannot be any memory leaks after a program exits.

If you want to create a leak to see what it looks like, you could create a new `CalculatorBrain` multiple times while your program is running, but forget to release the unused versions.  In this scenario, as your program runs, more and more instances of `CalculatorBrain` would accumulate.  On iOS and other embedded systems, this will generally crash your program.  On a modern 64 bit computer it will gradually fill up the available swap space until you run out of swap, address space, or some other resource -- causing the program to crash or making the system very unresponsive.

Standard practice is to not care about deallocating objects which are supposed to exist for the entire program's run.

Comment: By container object do you mean the class/object that calls the alloc & init?

Comment: @Jon: I'm talking about the instance which has the "brain" instance variable.  (I shouldn't have used 'container' because that word really means something else.)

Comment: Thanks. However I only have this one controller with brain in it.  If it was set to nil and the application exited would it not tidy it up? According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075069/iphone-delegate-controller-dealloc it will. Your answer says it wont...

Comment: @Jon: Set what to nil?  When I say "deallocated" I actually mean the `dealloc` method specifically.

Comment: In your answer you said brain = nil; If that was coded and the app exited would there be a memory leak?

Comment: @Jon: In theory, if you set the ivar `brain` to `nil` without calling `release` on the object, and there is no other reachable reference to `brain`, **THEN** it is possible (but not guaranteed) that the leak detector will detect a leak.

Answer (score 0):

The analyzer cannot find all memory leaks. As far as it is concerned, storing the instance into the ivar doesn't leak it from that method, and then in dealloc it doesn't realize that the ivar should be released. XCode 4 may have improved in this respect, I don't recall (I still use XCode 3 myself).

As for the performance tool, remember that an object won't be considered leaked until nothing holds a reference to it anymore. So even though your controller doesn't deallocate the brain, the brain won't be considered leaked until the controller is deallocated (or receives a brain transplant). Also, note that on *nix-like systems, memory allocations are automatically cleaned up on process exit. So it isn't really a leak if you allocate memory for objects that should exist for the lifetime of your process (e.g. the app delegate and anything it permanently holds on to) and rely on this behavior to free it on process exit.

Answer (score 0):

Well... it's true that leaks can't detect all memory leaks, but let's say that you are doing this:

```
myIvarBrain=[self brain];
```

If you are giving it to an iVar (released in the dealloc of your class, and without accessors), actually there is no leak at all. The returned RC is one and it will be one since the deallocation of your class. If you don't release it in the dealloc, you should wait a dealloc of your class to see a memory leak.
Does make sense?