# Using the applicationWillTerminate method doesn't seem to be working

Tags: iphone, uiapplicationdelegate, savestate

I am wanting to save some app state data for when the user is quitting the app. I am thinking that I should be using the applicationWillTerminate method inside of my appDelegate, but when I try and do anything there, it's not doing anything:

```
- (void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"test");
 }
```

When I run my app, and do some stuff, and hit the home button to quit the app, nothing comes over the console...

Do I have to implement the applicationWillTerminate method in the appDelegate? The user of my app will most likely be in a Reader view when they leave, is there anyway to implement the app will close method there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this  link [iPhone simulator and applicationWillTerminate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368021/iphone-simulator-and-applicationwillterminate) for older iOS versions;

but remember the Home button does not necessarily terminate the application is ios4... you should use `applicationDidEnterBackground` but would suggest both places `applicationWillTerminate` and `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Adding the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to your application’s `Info.plist` file and setting its value to `YES` will make you application quit when you hit the home button, even on iOS4

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 4, the `applicationWillTerminate:` method is only called if you opt out of the background execution model. In the standard iOS 4 application lifecycle, applications are suspended (not terminated) when the home button is pressed. Your application delegate will receive an `applicationWillResignActive:` message followed by an `applicationDidEnterBackground:` message. The `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method is a good place to save user data.